# ajax call for galleria galleries

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm wanting onclick subtitles that have a different galleria gallery in each one (not pop up style).  I have the galleria galleries in separate html pages and now I'm wanting do do an ajax call on my showcase page to bring up the gallery upon clicking the subtitle.

Where am I going wrong?

This is the code for my php page so far:

```
    <?
$main_content .= '

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.9.min.js"></script> 

            <style>
            #galleria{ width: 700px; height: 400px; background: #000; } 
            </style>


            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#agricultural").click(function() {
                changeProduct($(this), $(this));

$("#galleria").load("AgriculturalSlideshow.html");
            });
            $("#commercial").click(function() {
                changeProduct($(this), $(this));

$("#galleria").load("CommercialSlideshow.html");
            });
            $("#community").click(function() {
                changeProduct($(this), $(this));

$("#galleria").load("communityslideshow.html");
            });
            $("#industrial").click(function() {
                changeProduct($(this), $(this));

$("#galleria").load("industrialslideshow.html");
            });
            $("#recreational").click(function() {
                changeProduct($(this), $(this));

$("#galleria").load("recreationalslideshow.html");
            });
            $("#underconstruction").click(function() {
                changeProduct($(this), $(this));

$("#galleria").load("underconstructionslideshow.html");
            });

        function changeProduct(menu, obj){
            $(".productMenu").css({"color":"#000000"});
            $(".prodContent").hide();
            $(menu).css({"color":"#a50000"});
            $(obj).fadeIn();
        }
        });
    </script>
    <div style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:50px;">
        <div class="pageHeader">
            SHOWCASE
        </div>
        <div class="content">   
        <div style="padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;">
            <span class="productMenu" id="agricultural" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:20px; color:#a50000">AGRICULTURAL</span>       
            <span class="productMenu" id="commercial" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:20px;">COMMERCIAL</span>
            <span class="productMenu" id="community" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:20px;">COMMUNITY</span>
            <span class="productMenu" id="industrial" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:20px;">INDUSTRIAL</span>
            <span class="productMenu" id="recreational" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:20px;">RECREATIONAL</span>
            <span class="productMenu" id="underconstruction" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:20px;">UNDERCONSTRUCTION</span>             
        </div>
         <div id="galleria"> 
        </div>
        <script>
            Galleria.loadTheme("galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js");
            Galleria.run("#galleria");
        </script>




        <div style="clear:both; text-align:justify; text-align-last:justify;padding-top:50px;">
            AGRICULTURAL | COMMERCIAL | RESIDENTIAL & GARAGES | GOVERNMENT | INDUSTRIAL | INSTITUTIONAL | RECREATIONAL
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use urls not file paths in ajax requests so `../AgriculturalSlideshow.html` doesn't work. You have to use an url without `../`.

Either the absolute url with `http://` or the correct relative url.

And your `jquery click event` **is overwritten** by the `onclick attribute`. So call `changeProduct` inside your jquery eventhandler and remove the onclick attribute from the span elements.

There were are also missing semicolons in `changeProduct`:

```
     function changeProduct(menu, obj){
        $(".productMenu").css({"color":"#000000"});
        $(".prodContent").hide();
        $(menu).css({"color":"#a50000"});
        $(obj).fadeIn();
    }
```

Have a look at that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YqFEn/2/

I would suggest you to use chrome developer tools or firebug (Firefox) to debug your javascript. That way you can easily check syntax errors or ajax requests.

By the way the parameters `menu` and `obj` are exactly the same so something will not work as expected there. But the ajax requests should work.

**For your additional problems**

You could add a div box below the subtitles and then load all the galleries into this div box.

```
<div id="gal_content"></div>
```

And adjust your `load` statements:

```
$("#gal_content").load("AgriculturalSlideshow.html");
```

Comment: sorry i didn't mean to have those in there when I copied and pasted the code I was trying something since nothing else was working

Comment: Have a look at my update. You have two click events defined. onclick attribute and jquery eventhandler.

Comment: just tried that and nothing comes up when I click on my subtitles

Comment: Updated again. Should work now. You should definitely start debugging with the right tools.

Comment: Thanks that helped me quite a bit. It doesn't work like I want it to (subtitles and galleries get all messed up when clicked) but I'll keep working on it.

Comment: do you have some references as to where I can begin looking for the code to hide my galleries and keep all the subtitles above the gallery?

Comment: tried and it's still not working, think I gonna try a different route

Comment: What is still not like it should be and are there any errors in the console.

Comment: I was able to get one gallery going but as soon as I clicked the next subtitle it was blank, any ideas?

Comment: I can't help you any further because I don't know your updated code. I would also suggest you to read a bit more into jquery because your problems are pretty basic. You can solve them by yourself with a bit deeper knowledge of the functions you are using. For me the problem is that you are still overwriting your subtitles with your [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) contents.